# a question about citation in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am still new to latex and writing my first report using it. My problem is that the citation are not alwas working. Some of the citations are working with no problem while others are showed in my report as [?].

The message I am getting in overleaf is {Package natbib Warning: Citation `HOBOm' on page 3 undefined on input line 6.,You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.}

Even though my bibliography file does contain this source. Here is the source as included in my ref.bib file. I have also made sure that the label is correct

My code of .bib file

```
@book{Hakim,
    author    = {Gregory Hakim and Jerome Patoux},
    title     = {Weather a concise introduction},
    year      = {2021},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    address   = {United Kingdom},
}
@proceedings{HOBOm,
    author = {Onset},
    title = {HOBO Data Logging Rain Gauge (RG3 and RG3-M) Manual},
    year = {2012},
    url = {https://www.onsetcomp.com/sites/default/files/resources-documents/10241-M%20MAN-RG3%20and%20RG3-M.pdf},
}
@article{virga,
    title="Is virga rain that evaporates before reaching the ground?",
    author="Fraser, Alistair B and Bohren, Craig F",
    journal="Monthly weather review",
    volume="120",
    number="8",
    pages="1565--1571",
    year="1992",
    URL={https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/mwre/120/8/1520-0493_1992_120_1565_ivrteb_2_0_co_2.xml},
}
@book{modern,
    author    = {Devore, Jay L and Berk, Kenneth N and Carlton, Matthew A and others},
    title     = {Modern mathematical statistics with applications},
    year      = {2012},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address   = {USA},
}

@book{foken,
    author    = "Thomas Foken",
    title     = "Springer Handbook of Atmospheric Measurements",
    year      = "2021",
    publisher = "Springer Nature",
    address   = "Switzerland",
}



@article{x,
  title={Temporal precipitation variability versus altitude on a tropical high mountain: Observations and mesoscale atmospheric modelling},
  author={M{\"o}lg, Thomas and Chiang, John CH and Gohm, Alexander and Cullen, Nicolas J},
  journal={Quarterly Journal of the Royal Meteorological Society: A journal of the atmospheric sciences, applied meteorology and physical oceanography},
  volume={135},
  number={643},
  pages={1439--1455},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
}

@misc{stamey2008modern,
  title={Modern mathematical Statistics with applications},
  author={Stamey, James},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
}
@article{uncertainity,
  title={Evaluation of measurement uncertainty for thermometers with calibration equations},
  author={Chen, Chiachung},
  journal={Accreditation and quality assurance},
  volume={11},
  pages={75--82},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer},
}
@manual{Tiny_guide,
    title = "Rugged, waterproof data logger with temperature and relative humidity probe",
    key="Gemnini Data Loggers",
    url= "https://assets.geminidataloggers.com/pdfs/original/3753-tgp-4505.pdf",
    year= "2019"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This bib item may be blocked by an error in the previous item in the `.bib` file.  A frequent problem is absence of a required comma.  (There really should be one at the end of the url line in this item.)  Check the `.blg` file for errors in compiling the `.bbl` file.